# find rows via a chain of foreign keys

Tags: sql, t-sql, foreign-keys

Suppose I have the following tables:

Star with Id and Name
Planet with Id, Name, and StarId
Moon with Id, Name, and PlanetId

Both `StarId` and `PlanetId` are foreign keys.
In entity framework core, it is easy to find all of the moons that belong to a particular star:

```
   var moons = await db.Moons.Where(m => m.Planet.Star.Name == "Sun").ToListAsync();
```

My question is whether there is a quick way to do the same thing in transact SQL. One could do it with joins. But every example I've seen involves a lot more wordiness than one would like.

Comment: You could create a view to abstract the joins, but they need to happen somewhere.

Comment: Perhaps I just need to accept that Tsql does not have an easy way to specify something like `moon.planet.star.name`?

Comment: I don't know of a way. Are you familiar with views? You can join your tables once and just reference it. Certainly it isn't as flexible as what you have in your question, but I think that is as close as your going to get.

Comment: T-SQL Isn't an programming language, @WilliamJockusch , `moon.planet.star.name` would *not* refer to the `name` property, of the `star` property, of the `planet`, property of the `moon` object. In would (likely) try to reference the column `name`, in the table/object `star`, in the schema `planet` in the database `moon`. Treat T-SQL, or SQL, as what is it, a query language. All languages are not designed equally, nor to be similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the moons around our sun, you would use:

```
select m.*
from Moon m join
     Planet p
     on p.Id = m.planetid join
     Star s
     on s.Id = p.starid
where s.name = 'Sun';
```

This is perhaps not as concise as what your syntax, but it is quite simple actually.

Some people don't like explicit joins, so they might write:

```
select m.*
from moons m
where m.planet_id in (select p.planet_id
                      from planets p
                      where p.star_id in (select s.star_id
                                          from stars s
                                          where s.name = 'Sun'
                                         )
                     );
```

This style doesn't appeal to me and it tends to generate worse execution plans.

Answer (score 0):

Based on some comments, the answer appears to be "No, there is not. The join syntax is necessary." It is described nicely in another answer.